# Confusion about the way C handles strings

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Why wouldn't

```
   char *name = "asd";
   printf("%p\n%p", (void *)&name, (void *)&name[0]);
```

give the same output as

```
char name[] = "asd";
printf("%p\n%p", (void *)&name, (void *)&name[0]);
```

I've read that C takes strings as a pointer to their first char, till it reaches the `'\0'` but the code above doesn't like it, so it is confusing for a C beginner.

Comment: This code is not C++.  Removing the tag.

Comment: string literal will add '\0' in the end while converting to chars. That's why it's `name[4]` instead of 3.

Answer (score 5):

First, let's give your two variables different names and contents, so we can clearly tell them apart.

```
char *namep = "asd";
char namea[] = "zxc";
```

These result in data structures which might look like this:

```
       +-------+
namep: |   *   |
       +---|---+
           |
          /
         |
         V
       +---+---+---+----+
       | a | s | d | \0 |
       +---+---+---+----+

       +---+---+---+----+
namea: | z | x | c | \0 |
       +---+---+---+----+
```

Now let's look at your two `printf` calls:

```
printf("%p\n%p", (void *)&namep, (void *)&namep[0]);
```

Now, `&namep` gives you the address of the `namep` pointer.
But `&namep[0]` gives you the address of the first character in the pointed-to string (`a`).  If you had printed

```
printf("%p\n", (void *)namep);
```

you would have seen the same thing.

```
printf("%p\n%p", (void *)&namea, (void *)&namea[0]);
```

Here, `&namea` gives you the address of the array.
And `&namea[0]` gives you the address of its first character (`z`) — which is the same place.
And in fact, due to the special handling (the "decay" of arrays into pointers), if you had said

```
printf("%p\n", (void *)namea);
```

you would also have seen the same thing.

You asked:

> I've read that C takes strings as a pointer to their first char, till it reaches the `'\0'`.

That's correct.

Suppose you wrote the code

```
char *p;
for(p = namep; *p != '\0'; p++)
    putchar(*p);
```

This would print your `namep` string, `asd`.  There's no mystery here.  `namep` was already a pointer, pointing at the first character of the string, so this scrap of code takes its own pointer `p`, which starts pointing where `namep` points, and prints the pointed-to characters until it gets to the terminating `\0`.

What's perhaps more surprising is that you can do *exactly* the same thing with `namea`:

```
char *p;
for(p = namea; *p != '\0'; p++)
    putchar(*p);
```

This works, too, printing `zxc`, and if you don't believe me, I encourage you to type it into your C compiler and try it.

Now, you may be asking, if `p` is a pointer and `namea` is an array, how can the loop initialization `p = namea` work?  And this, again, is due to the "decay" of arrays to pointers.  Again, when you try to use `namea`'s value like this, what you get — the value that gets assigned to `p` — is automatically a pointer to `namea`'s first element.  And of course that's just what you want.  `p` starts there, and prints characters 'til it finds a `\0`, thus printing `zxc`.