# Shouldn't a character pointer array, print a pointer? Why does it print the string it is pointed to?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, printf, c-strings

I have the code below:

```
    static char *name[] = {
            "January",
            "February",
            "March",
    };

    printf("%s", name[0]);
```

When I passed printf with `name[0]`, it prints `January`. But shouldn't it print the `address` of January, since the array above stores a `pointer` to January?

Comment: `printf`'s `%s` format wants a pointer.  Your `name` array is an array of pointers.  So `name[0]` is a pointer, and everyone's happy.  (And, more specifically, `%s` wants, and `name[0]` is, a pointer to `char`, that points to the beginning of a valid, null-terminated string.)

Comment: If you want address, use `%p`.

Comment: See [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69609939) for some possibly-relevant information.

Comment: `name[0]` stores a pointer to the first character of a non-modifiable, anonymous array of `char` that is the string literal `"January"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion specifier `%s` interprets the corresponding argument as a pointer to first character of a string that is outputted until the terminating zero character `'\0'` is encountered.

If you want to output the pointer itself then you should write

```
printf( "%p", ( void * )name[0] );
```

Pay attention to that in this declaration

```
static char *name[] = {
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
};
```

the string literals used as initializers are implicitly converted to pointers to their first characters and these pointers are stored in the array `name`.